# How to configure WCAG2_1 in VeraPDF?

Tags: java, wcag

I'm trying to validate a PDF file with VeraPDF using WCAG2_1 as a validation methodology.

If I change the methodology to another such as PDFA_4, everything works fine, however with WCAG2_1 something goes wrong.

Right now I have the following:

```
  public void test()
      throws FileNotFoundException, EncryptedPdfException, ModelParsingException, ValidationException {
    VeraGreenfieldFoundryProvider.initialise();
    //PdfBoxFoundryProvider.initialise();
    PDFAFlavour flavour = PDFAFlavour.WCAG2_1;
    PDFAParser parser = Foundries.defaultInstance().createParser(new FileInputStream(
        "/myfile.pdf"), flavour);
    PDFAValidator validator = Foundries.defaultInstance().createValidator(flavour, true);
    ValidationResult result = validator.validate(parser);

    ListIterator<TestAssertion> ltr = result.getTestAssertions().listIterator();
    while (ltr.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(ltr.next().getErrorMessage());
    }

    assertTrue(result.isCompliant());
  }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.verapdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>parser</artifactId>
      <version>1.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.verapdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdf-model</artifactId>
      <version>1.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.verapdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.verapdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>verapdf-xmp-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.verapdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-model</artifactId>
      <version>1.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.verapdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox-validation-model</artifactId>
      <version>1.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.verapdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>wcag-validation</artifactId>
      <version>1.21.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

[image: verapdf-core-1.21.1 methodologies]

I have this output:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: PDFAFlavour wcag2 is not supported
> by this directory.
>
> at
> org.verapdf.pdfa.validation.profiles.ProfileDirectoryImpl.getValidationProfileByFlavour(ProfileDirectoryImpl.java:104)
> at
> org.verapdf.pdfa.validation.validators.ValidatorFactory.createValidator(ValidatorFactory.java:69)

What can I do to support WCAG2_1 methodology?